# If you have a very distorted image, would affine transformations applied to images make object detection algorithms make more mistakes?

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, computer-vision, object-detection, affine-transformations

If you have a very distorted video/image, would affine transformations of the images make object detection algorithms make more mistakes compared to a normal camera?

Comment: By affine transformations, do you mean rotations and scaling (i.e. do you have in mind something more specific)? You should also explain **why** you're asking this question.